# EasyMock gentle introduction?

Tags: unit-testing, mocking, easymock

I am completely baffled while trying to use EasyMock. Does anybody know of a (very) gentle introduction to EasyMock?

I already heavily use TDD, and I use mocking (which I guess is almost a prerequisite for doing TDD). I have just never used a framework for mocking before.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are some articles you might like:

- [Easier testing with EasyMock](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/java/library/j-easymock/index.html)
- [Unit testing with JUnit and EasyMock](http://www.michaelminella.com/testing/unit-testing-with-junit-and-easymock.html)
- [Mock Object Testing With EasyMock 2](http://www.realsolve.co.uk/site/tech/easymock.php)
- [Getting Started with EasyMock2](http://today.java.net/pub/a/today/2006/06/20/getting-started-with-easymock-2.html)

You could also check out other mocking frameworks such as [Mockito](http://mockito.org/), [PowerMock](http://code.google.com/p/powermock/) and [JMockit](http://code.google.com/p/jmockit/).

Answer (score 2):

How about their own Documentation? http://easymock.org/EasyMock3_0_Documentation.html

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this tutorial?   http://www.vogella.de/articles/EasyMock/article.html

Do you already have a background in Test Driven Development?  If not, I'd get my hands on a copy of Roy Osherove's book The Art of Unit Testing.  http://artofunittesting.com/